# Count Of rows since last occurence of value in specific column

Tags: t-sql

Take a look at this SQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cefe0b/2/0

Per request, here is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE #JobExecutions
(
    JobExecutionID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    JobID INT NOT NULL,
    StartTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    EndTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    RunStatus VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (1, '10/01/2020 14:37:28', '10/01/2020 14:41:03', 'Succeeded')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (2, '10/01/2020 15:37:28', '10/01/2020 15:41:03', 'Succeeded')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (3, '10/01/2020 16:37:28', '10/01/2020 16:41:03', 'Succeeded')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (1, '10/02/2020 14:37:28', '10/02/2020 14:41:03', 'Succeeded')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (2, '10/02/2020 15:37:28', '10/02/2020 15:41:03', 'Succeeded')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (3, '10/02/2020 16:37:28', '10/02/2020 16:41:03', 'Succeeded')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (1, '10/03/2020 14:37:28', '10/03/2020 14:41:03', 'Failed')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (2, '10/03/2020 15:37:28', '10/03/2020 15:41:03', 'Failed')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (3, '10/03/2020 16:37:28', '10/03/2020 16:41:03', 'Failed')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (1, '10/04/2020 14:37:28', '10/04/2020 14:41:03', 'Succeeded')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (2, '10/04/2020 15:37:28', '10/04/2020 15:41:03', 'Succeeded')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (3, '10/04/2020 16:37:28', '10/04/2020 16:41:03', 'Succeeded')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (1, '10/05/2020 14:37:28', '10/05/2020 14:41:03', 'Failed')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (2, '10/05/2020 15:37:28', '10/05/2020 15:41:03', 'Failed')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (1, '10/06/2020 14:37:28', '10/06/2020 14:41:03', 'Failed')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (2, '10/06/2020 15:37:28', '10/06/2020 15:41:03', 'Failed')
INSERT INTO #JobExecutions (JobID, StartTime, EndTime, RunStatus) VALUES (1, '10/07/2020 14:37:28', '10/07/2020 14:41:03', 'Failed')
```

I have a set of jobs for which I would like to count the number of times they have failed in a row since their last successful run.

My final resultset should look like this:

```
+-------+-----------------------------+
| JobID | TimesFailedSinceLastSuccess |
+-------+-----------------------------+
|     1 |                           3 |
|     2 |                           2 |
|     3 |                           0 |
+-------+-----------------------------+
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can job executions for a single job overlap? How would that be handled?

Comment: Don't just put your data in a fiddle; put it in the qusetion as well. Fiddles can be deleted, and don't work for everyone. For example, at work, I can't access that link.

Comment: Good question. JobExecutions for a job cannot overlap.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you. I will update right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out my brain was not as blocked as I thought. Here is my approach. However, if there is a more elegant way, please post.

```
WITH lastRunJob
AS (SELECT MAX(EndTime) AS LastSuccessEndTime,
           JobID
    FROM #JobExecutions
    WHERE RunStatus = 'Succeeded'
    GROUP BY JobID)
SELECT t1.JobID,
       COUNT(t2.JobExecutionID)
FROM lastRunJob t1
    OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #JobExecutions t2
    WHERE t1.JobID = t2.JobID
          AND t2.EndTime > t1.LastSuccessEndTime
          AND t2.RunStatus = 'Failed'
) t2
GROUP BY t1.JobID;
```